# adaptive colum width in a fluid design

Tags: css

I would like to create a grid with 4 columns. Columns width should fit to there respective contents, and gutters should all share the same width changing depending on the columns width. The tricky thing is that the total width of the container / grid should be adjustable dynamically, as it should be a responsive design.

Here is a scheme that's explains what i want to achieve :
[image: scheme]

And [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bestiole/njnxrqau/) trying with margin-left:auto (doesn't work)

```
nav ul {
    width:80%; /* fluid design */
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

I can use latest CSS3, Sass, Compass and Susy. But i haven't found any way to do it yet. It seems Susy doesn't allow me to have columns adjusting their width to their content - or i haven't found how. Does anyone have any idea ? thanks !

Comment: This may help you a lot... for this and for the future: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: If you're looking for an existing soluion, consider [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?  That has a 12 cell grid system built in.  So for four columns your would use 3 boostrap cells per column.

Comment: i won't use bootstrap because i don't want my website to be white and blue :) i'm kidding a bit but i say this because it shows poor possibilities of customization and i think it's a bit killing a fly with a steamroller. btw i don't think its grid system is able to answer this problem : i don't think it would be more efficient than Susy (the columns width would not adapt to their content) and i would need to add classes in the html code, which is not great to dissociate content (html) from design (css)

Comment: Dont' worry and, sadly, get use to. While many downvotes are fair (mayoritie) you may find people VERY eager to downvote questions (and answers) without leaving any comment. This is (imo) the only problem of stackoverflow (which is one of the greatest web I have ever seen... when need of help at my work). You don't need much rep to start downvoting. Just today I was downvoted on an answer mark by the op as good probably (I guess) because someone who made another answer got pissed.

Comment: But at the end, dont' worry much, You may find those downvotes won't make your rep go down a lot if you keep beign active and trying to help others (and making valid questions). It's just a -2, and a single upvote is +10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the link I posted as a comment, you may use flexboxes to achieve your layout.

Basically if you give your container this CSS:

```
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

your content will adapt to the 100% of the container and space between elements will always be the same.

Here you have a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uu9wemke/2/)** as an example. Try writting more on any div to see it growing.

I've added a margin right to the elements so there's always a gap between elements. If you remove that margin, when no room the space between elements will be 0.

There's more options avalaibles like giving your elements the option to shrink if no room enough with `flex-shrink:` and many others...

More info about flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: great ! i didn't knew about this flex functionnality. Here is [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bestiole/njnxrqau/5/).
works like a charm ! thanks a lot !

Comment: Np mate. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time the only way to achieve this is through Javascript. CSS is not capable of finding the width based on your content.